# Is Memory release for Map Data Members in Class during exceptions

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
typedef struct {
    guint8  mode;     
    vector <string> match_src;  
} structConfig_t;


map < guint64, vector <structConfig_t> > mapConfig_t;
```

and then have class as follows

```
class Config {
  private :
     mapConfig_t mapConfig;

  public :
     Config(const char * config_fn) throw (string);
}
```

The constructor parses each line in the file provided at "config_fn" , and builds the mapConfig data structure. On parse issues , the constructor raises exception.

Curious to know , what happens if parse fails towards midst of the file and raises the exception and mapConfig has data 
being parsed till now , will the memory being used by mapConfig till then get relinquished automatically in such scenarios ?

Answer (score 1):

> if parse fails [...] and raises the exception [...], will the memory being used by mapConfig till then get relinquished automatically in such scenarios ?

Yes; if an exception is thrown out of the constructor body, then all members and base-class sub-objects will be destroyed automatically. If the object was being created using `new`, then the allocated memory will also be released automatically.

By the way, it's a bit unusual to throw `string`; it's much more common to throw something derived from `std::exception`. Also, exception specifiers are generally regarded as a bad idea, and have been deprecated in the latest version of the language.